# Google Contact API Fetch Contacts related to a Contact Group

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I would like to know how to get all contacts related to a group.
Let's say I have a contact group named "My Special Group" and the ID is xxxxxxx.I just want to retrieve contact under the "My Special Group" only.

I have already tried this Request URI and test it on oauth2 playground:

1. `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/?group=xxxxxxx.`
2. `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/myemail%40gmail.com/full/?group=xxxxxxx.`

And the result is:

```
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
 <error>
  <domain>GData</domain>
  <code>invalid</code>
  <internalReason>Supposed groupUri xxxxxxxxdoes not match template</internalReason>
 </error>
</errors>
```

What exactly the correct Request URI to retrieving contacts related to specific group?

Already walked around stackoverflow & the answer is exactly what I do above.Its failed.

Answer (score 5):

Okay fellas. I found the answer.Here it is.

The supposed Request URI to retrieve contacts related to a contact group is like this:
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?&group=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/yourmail%40gmail.com/base/xxxxxxx

where xxxxxx is the contact group id.

Before this I'm using this Request URI :
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?&group=xxxxxxx

where xxxxxx is the contact group id and the result is will be failed because I'm just put the group id instead of use full uri of contacts group .

So that's all.Hope its help.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Can anyone help?